# Trying to resolve arguments and constructing arguments for each variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

Somehow I am getting the error that `initializer_list` is not a valid template argument for `_Types`. I try to create an shared_ptr from a template argument and pass its arguments inside the  `make_shared` parameter.

I have this method that searches for the hashcode of a class and creates the instance of the class and returns it as `scope_ref => shared_ptr`.

```
template <typename _Ty>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr inline scope_ref<_Ty> _Resolve_arg() const {
    auto found = map_.find(_Hash_code<_Ty>());
    return found->second();
}
```

This method is registering classes with its hashcode and an factory function inside a map.

```
    template <typename _Ty_base, typename _Ty_implementation, typename... _Implementation_args>
    constexpr inline void register() {
            // Doing some static asserts...

        map_[_Hash_code<_Ty_base>()] = []() -> scope_ref<_Ty_base> {

            // This works perfectly fine witout arguments.
            if constexpr (sizeof...(_Implementation_args) <= 0) {
                return std::make_shared<_Ty_implementation>();
            }

            // Here comes the issue...
            return std::make_shared<_Ty_implementation>({ _Resolve_arg<_Implementation_args>()... });
        };
    }
```

My idea is to call for each argument of `_Ty_implementation` its factory method that is saved inside the `map_`.

Comment: names starting with `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved

Comment: `make_shared` tries to deduce the type of its arguments. `{ ... }` is not an expression and has no type, hence no type can be deduced. OTOH, `SomeType{...}` is an expression of type `SomeType`.